# How To Mathematically Slice A Parabolic Trough at an Angle?

Tags: conic-sections

Given a [Parabolic Trough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trough) is defined as $y=x^2$ and extending infinitely in the z direction. How may I find the equation of the curve obtained through slicing the parabolic trough using a plane through the x-axis and at an angle $\theta$ from the z-axis?

[image]

Comment: You cannot find "the equation" for this curve, if by that you mean a single equation in only $x$, $y$, and $z$. You can find a parameterization of this curve though in terms of some time variable $t$; is that what you seek?

Comment: @alex.jordan That is indeed! If there is a way to use complex numbers I would be even more thrilled.

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(t,t^2,t\cot\theta)$